# Could two processors have same virtual address map to same physical address under windows OS in case of shared memory?

Tags: windows, operating-system

If two processors have shared memory, is it possible two processors have the same virtual address to the physical address of the shared memory under windows os?

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible.  Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question correctly, but if you are asking if two different processors could map the same virtual memory to physical memory, then the answer is yes.
You could have multiple mappings to same physical memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The physical address is completely independent of the logical (or virtual) address.

If two processes mapping logical pages to the same physical page frame, the two processes could many different logical addresses or the same logical addresses to that physical page frame. In most cases (as the result of pure random chance), processes have different logical addresses when they map to the same page frame BUT they could just as well have the same logical addresses mapping to the same physical page frame.